# Call a method of the Main Activity from a map fragment doesn't works

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I'm making an app in Android that connects to a REST server, from where it returns the coordenates to generate markers in a Map Fragment.
I have two types of markers, those that are from an activity and those that are from a commentary. The comment's markers are blue and the activity's are red.
I have these methods in the `Main` activity that retrieve the coordinates and the tittle for the markers.

```
public String[][] marcaCom() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String[][] g;
    MarcadorComentario marcadorComentario = new MarcadorComentario();
    marcadorComentario.MarcadorComentario(idGir);
    marcadorComentario.execute();
    g = marcadorComentario.get();
    return g;
}

public String[][] marcaAct() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String[][] h;
    MarcadorActividad marcadorActividad = new MarcadorActividad();
    marcadorActividad.MarcadorActividad(idGir);
    marcadorActividad.execute();
    h = marcadorActividad.get();
    return h;
}
```

`marcaAct()` is the method that retrieves the data for the activities and `marcaCom()` does the same for commentaries.
Then I call them from a Map Fragment:

```
public class BitacoraApoderadoFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    String[][] comentarios;
    String[][] activ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bitacora_apoderado, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        try {
            comentarios = mainActivity.marcaCom();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(comentarios.length);
        for (int c=0;c<comentarios.length;c++){
            double comLat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(comentarios[c][1]));
            double comLng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(comentarios[c][2]));
            LatLng com = new LatLng(comLat,comLng);
            MarkerOptions comen = new MarkerOptions();
            comen.position(com).title(String.valueOf(comentarios[c][0])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            map.addMarker(comen);
        }

        try {
            activ = mainActivity.marcaAct();
            System.out.println(activ.length);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<activ.length;i++){
            double acLat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(activ[i][1]));
            double acLng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(activ[i][2]));
            System.out.println("WHAT HAPPENED");
            LatLng ac = new LatLng(acLat,acLng);
            MarkerOptions actividad = new MarkerOptions();
            actividad.position(ac).title(String.valueOf(activ[i][0]));
            map.addMarker(actividad);
        }

        double one = -33.4724727;
        double two = -70.9100262;
        LatLng onetwo = new LatLng(one,two);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(onetwo,1));
    }
```

And I do some `System.out.print` to see the what is happening with the data. And here is the problem... for some strange reason the code works... but only for the comments. When I run the application and open the map, I see the blue markers of the comments, but the activity's markers aren't there.
When I use `system.out.println(activ.length)`. I got 0 in the Run: log. So the thing is that it is not bringing back the data from `marcaAct()`.
But the thing is that I created a button from another activity, this button retrieves the data from `marcaAct()` and `marcaCom()` and with some for that show the data via `System.out.print`.
Here is this button's method:

```
public void marcadores(View view) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String[][] h = marcaAct();
    for(int i = 0; i<h.length;i++){
        for(int e=0;e<3;e++){
            System.out.print(" "+h[i][e]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(h.length);
    String[][] m = marcaCom();
    for(int i = 0;i<m.length;i++){
        for(int e=0;e<3;e++){
            System.out.print(" "+m[i][e]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(m.length);
}
```

And the result of this method is:

```
I/System.out:  test00  15.6323613  13.5463462  
I/System.out:  test03  13.6323613  14.5463462  
I/System.out:  test02  16.6323613  13.5463462  
I/System.out: 3
```

I just pasted the results for the `system.out.print` of activities. Well there you can see that in this case the method brings the data as it is supposed to do. So my question is... Where is the error? What am I doing wrong here that causes this problem? Please I really need some help here. I didn't even knew how to google this "bug" so right now I'm completely lost.
For a moment I think about it being too much work for the app to do two calls to the server at the same time, so I commented the section that generates the comment's markers. But it didn't work.

PD. Sorry if my english is not accurate but I'm chilean so I don't really speak too much english.